# OpenLayer LineStrings to show label text on largest LineString

Tags: javascript, angular7, openlayers, openlayers-3

Currently, I have a requirement to show label on Linestrings(a group of LineString)geometry but want **only on the largest segment** to the label.
I am trying to set the style for rulerObject as

```
var rulerObject = olFeature({
  geometry: rulerGeometry //this is the geometry for all the linestrings.
});
rulerObject.setProperties({
  'labelText': "My Label"
});
```

But this is rendering "My Label" on all the segments.

How can I set style(label) of only the largest segment?

Answer (score 1):

For the text part of the style you would need a geometry function which finds the longest segment and returns that as the geometry to style the text

```
style: [
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      ...
      ...
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    geometry: function(feature) {
      let maxStart, maxEnd;
      let maxSquareLength = -1;
      feature.getGeometry().forEachSegment(function(start, end) {
        const dx = end[0] - start[0];
        const dy = end[1] - start[1];
        const squareLength = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        if (squareLength > maxSquareLength) {
          maxStart = start;
          maxEnd = end;
          maxSquareLength = squareLength;
        }
      });
      return new LineString([maxStart, maxEnd]);
    },
    text: mew Text({
      ...
      ...
    }),
  })
]
```